# I cant add 'C:\tools\cuda\bin' to my %PATH% in anaconda environment

Tags: anaconda, windows-10

I can't add 'C:\tools\cuda\bin' to my `%PATH%` in anaconda environment. I tried (inside environment):
`conda develop C:\tools\cuda\bin`, and also `SET PATH=C:\tools\cuda\bin;%PATH%`, I've tried it also in cmd : `SET PATH=C:\tools\cuda\bin;%PATH%`. My system is Win10

Answer (score 1):

You can run the below commands:

```
setx PATH C:\tools\cuda\bin;%PATH%
```

And add `/m` if you need to add it to system env vars (this requires admin):

```
setx PATH C:\tools\cuda\bin;%PATH% /m
```

From here: https://superuser.com/a/79614/1195070 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/28778358/13710015.